# XAMPP throws error while running Python script [OSX]

Tags: python-2.7, xampp

I am trying to run python code on **XAMPP** on my MAC system. I have followed this [link](http://www.coding4developers.com/python/setting-up-python-and-pymysql-on-your-mac/).

Now when I run php code then its runs successfully but when I try to run my .py file then gives me following error :

```
Server error!

The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete
your request.

Error message:  End of script output before headers: loginService.py

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 500

localhost Apache/2.4.25 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.2l PHP/7.1.6
mod_perl/2.0.8-dev Perl/v5.16.3
```

-> I have made the changes to httpd.conf : AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl 
.py 
-> Python version : Python 2.7.10

I have my .php and .py file in "htdocs" folder, but lots of post suggest that the .py file should be in "cgi-bin" folder. [cgi-bin folder is write protected, not able to put files there]

Please help. Thank you